C# TCP/IP can't connect via port
I'm making an app to send messages to each other on a LAN server. I'm using c# forms apps to do so and im creating a server using tcp/ip connection. I can ping it and connect to it when I try. But when I try to connect using
"telnet 192.168.186 5000" 
command on a different pc than mine that also connected to the same wifi it refuses and says it's 'cause of my port, I guess?
Error code in turkish
here it says

"C:\Users\mehme>telnet 192.168.56.1 5000
Connecting 192.168.56.1...Failed to connect to host, port1 5000: Connection failed"

and I cant fix it. My port is opened manually and I'm checking it on cmd and yes, it works. Like i said it works on me but the problem is other PCs
my server code is =
class Server
{
    static TcpListener server;
    static bool isRunning = true;
    static string serverIP;

    static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (s, e) =>
        {
            isRunning = false;
            server.Stop();
        };

        int port = 5000;
        serverIP = GetLocalIPAddress();
        Console.WriteLine($"Sunucu IP: {serverIP}");
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        server.Start();

        Console.WriteLine($"Sunucu {port} portunda dinlemeye başladı...");

        Thread listenerThread = new Thread(ListenForClients)
        {
            IsBackground = true
        };
        listenerThread.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Sunucu başlatıldı. Çıkmak için 'CTRL + C' kullanabilirsiniz.");

        // Sunucu ana döngüsü
        while (isRunning)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Ana döngüyü bloklamamak için bekleme
        }

        server.Stop();
    }

    static void ListenForClients()
    {
        while (isRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                if (server.Pending())
                {
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Thread clientThread = new Thread(() => HandleClient(client))
                    {
                        IsBackground = true
                    };
                    clientThread.Start();
                }

                Thread.Sleep(100); // CPU kullanımını azaltmak için kısa bekleme
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sunucu hatası: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }


    static void HandleClient(TcpClient client)
    {
        string clientIP = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine($"Bağlantı alındı: {clientIP}");

        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            // Kullanıcı durumunu güncelle (aktif yap)
            UpdateUserStatus(clientIP, true);

            // Aktif kullanıcıları çekip istemciye gönder
            string activeUsers = GetActiveUsers();
            byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(activeUsers);
            stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);

            Console.WriteLine($"Aktif kullanıcılar gönderildi: {activeUsers}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hata: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }

    static void UpdateUserStatus(string ip, bool isActive)
    {
        string connectionString = "**********************";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                // Kullanıcı IP'sine göre aktiflik durumunu güncelle
                string query = "INSERT INTO kullanicilar (ip_adresi, aktif) VALUES (@ip, @aktif) " +
                               "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE aktif = @aktif";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", ip);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aktif", isActive ? 1 : 0);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine($"IP: {ip}, Aktiflik durumu güncellendi: {(isActive ? 1 : 0)}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hata: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    static string GetActiveUsers()
    {
        string connectionString = "*****************";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                // Aktif kullanıcıların IP adreslerini getir
                string query = "SELECT ip_adresi FROM kullanicilar WHERE aktif = 1";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                List<string> activeUsers = new List<string>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    activeUsers.Add(reader.GetString(0)); // IP adresini listeye ekle
                }

                return string.Join(",", activeUsers); // Aktif kullanıcıları virgülle birleştir
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hata: " + ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

    static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (netInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    foreach (var addr in netInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        if (addr.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork && !IPAddress.IsLoopback(addr.Address))
                        {
                            return addr.Address.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yerel IP adresi alınırken hata oluştu: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return "127.0.0.1"; // Default olarak localhost döndür
    }

Is anything wrong with the code that blocks the other PCs?
I tried opening the port on firewall manually, then add a new one with
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 5000" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=5000

but still useless.

If you are trying to connect exclusively via WiFi, you need to make sure your WiFi router configuration allows accessing other clients on the same WiFi.

Also consider switching to ssh from the start. If you ever plan to go from local-network-only outward, you'll need to drop unsafe telnet anyway.

I'd also strongly advise against that sleep-loop. You are blocking the thread for absolutely no reason. It could do some work instead.

Can you ping the ip?

@shingo i can ping it and it works fine every time

@Filburt actually i am new to networking and its my finishing project on college so im relying on ChatGPT for most of the connection so I dont know why the sleep thread is there. And for some reason it all works now. When i first tried it on my router it didnt work. then i tried it with my phone connection and still didn't work but somehow its all good now. but thanks for the comments anyway its still useful. And i am curious to know how to use the threads well. Any suggestions?

check inbound rule
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="Open Port 5000"
and then config scope
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Open Port 5000" new remoteip=any
